# What software do you use to design your PCB in the robotics field?

Tags: software, circuit

What is the best software (despite the price) for designing the circuits and PCB boards for robots?

I mean having lots of components, different designing methods, best accuracy, ...

I myself use the Altium Designer which I think answers my needs, but maybe there are better ones in the market i don't know about!

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a Robotics question, it seems like it would be better suited to the [Electronics StackExchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/), where this question has been address multiple times.

Comment: Better I edit my question. I mean in the robotics field. Like having the common parts used in robots and ...

Comment: @mjcarroll: I agree, unless someone can find a PCB package that is specifically designed for robotics. I doubt one exists.

Comment: @mjcarrol I agree this is not robotics specific enough. This should be asked on the electronics stackexchange

Comment: @SimpleCoder you are right. and the goal of the question is to find the best software which has the most compatibility with the components used in robots!

Comment: From the FAQ: [If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)

Answer (score 3):

We evaluated a variety of options and settled on Altium Designer at our shop.  We build nothing but robots with a team of 9 engineers.  I am not sure there is a ton of stuff that is robotic specific in a PCB design, but Altium allows us to interface directly with our Pick and Place machine, easily generate 3D models, and the integration of the library with Subversion makes teamwork easy.

Comment: I can echo this... Altium seems a good all-round package.